# Does pvcreate destroy all the data in a partition?

Tags: lvm

`man pvcreate` says

> pvcreate initializes a PV so that it is recognized as belonging to LVM, and allows the PV to be
>   used in a VG. A PV can be a disk partition, whole disk, meta device, or loopback file.
>
> For DOS disk partitions, the partition id should be set to 0x8e using fdisk(8), cfdisk(8), or a
>   equivalent. For GUID Partition Table (GPT), the id is E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-
>   238F2A3DF928. **For whole disk devices** only the partition table must be erased, which will
>   effectively destroy all data on that disk. This can be done by zeroing the first sector with:
>
> dd if=/dev/zero of=PhysicalVolume bs=512 count=1

If I use `pvcreate` to  mark **a disk** as a PV, does it mean that `pvcreate` will destroy all the data on a disk?

If I use `pvcreate` to mark **a partition** which contains a filesystem as a PV as a PV, will it destroy all the data in the filesystem?
If yes, does it mean that I can't move a filesystem from a partition to a LV, by `pvcreate` the partition as a PV (and then `lvcreate` a LV)?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "mark the disk as a PV"? Formatting an existing device as a PV will effectively lose said data in the same way that reformating a filesystem with a new filesystem will lose previous files.

Comment: What do you mean? Marking a device as a PV is not reformating a filesystem with a new filesystem.

Comment: Both involve removing the structure of a volume and replacing it with a new structure. You don't make a physical volume by "marking" it as such in the same way you don't make a filesystem by "marking" it - it needs formatting

Comment: `pvcreate` writes a header block.  This _may_ effectively make the data _structures_ (eg the filesystem superblock) unreadable, but the underlying data may be recoverable by a data recovery tool, or by `dd`.  From a typical end-user perspective, doing `pvcreate` on a block device may render the existing filesystem unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it say that pvcreate will destroy all the data on a disk,

While you may lose your data (in the same way that you can lose a sock behind the sofa).

No, if will not destroy all your data, and not even most of it. And, the quotes in your question, do not say that is destroys your data.

Neither `pvcreate`, nor `mkfs`, will securely delete a partition. They do not write to much of the partition. They only write what they need to, the rest is ignored.

When the OS reads this partition, it will see what type it is, and only follow links to initialised data, the rest with old stuff will be ignored. However if you choose to read it in a different way (forensic analysis), then you can see much of what was there before).

**However**

While we can not trust them to remove data, we also cannot trust them not to write over data. They write what they need to, this could over-write important data.

## Is there a way to convert from one file-system/PV to another?

I don't know. It depends what you are converting to what.

Comment: In what way does "will effectively destroy all data on that disk" not mean destroy all data on disk? If one is attempting to extend a volume by creating a logical volume and then growing that lv across disks, it's sort of important to know if all the data goes away.

Comment: @jorfus I think you are asking about the word "effectively". I agree it is not the best word. I think the text is using an unexpected meaning: It has the effect of being deleted (but is not).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a partition that contains a filesystem and data, and wish to change to LVM you will not be able to do so without moving the existing data elsewhere and then restoring. If you issue `pvcreate` on a partition containing a filesystem, the filesystem superblocks will be overwritten. All data on the disk will be rendered inaccessible. (though technically the data will be recoverable because the bits are still there, however the filenames are not) For your purposes, once you pvcreate on a disk the data that was there previously will be gone.

In this situation `pvcreate` will see a filesystem present and pop up a warning like

```
"Filesystem detected, overwrite? (y/n)"
```

There does not appear to be a way to pvcreate and preserve the existing filesystem. It would be really convenient if it were possible, but it appears not to be possible. The problem appears to be that LVM takes the first part of the disk which is the same part of the disk that the filesystem takes.
If you create a filesystem after you set up LVM, the filesystem gets written to the first part of the disk after the LVM information. Why can't we simply shift the filesystem superblocks? Because the space needed for that is already occupied by data. Why can't we shift that data? Because the shift needs to be reflected in the superblocks.

"Why can't we shift the data, update the superblocks, shift the superblocks, pvcreate on the disk, thus preserving the data?"

That is a fine question. If anyone knows of a tool to do that please post here because that seems to be the crux of the original question.